# Applet not iitialized when using Java Applet view

Tags: java, applet

I just finished my first programming class and did well in it and decided to start doing some graphics stuff from the book. The code complies fine then when ran in the applet viewer it says Start: Applet not initialized

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.awt.*;
/* <applet code = "test" width = 700 height = 700> </applet> */
public class HappyFace extends JApplet
{
  public void paint(Graphics canvas)
  {
   canvas.drawOval(100, 50, 200, 200);
   canvas.fillOval(155, 100, 10, 20);
   canvas.fillOval(230, 100, 10, 20);
   canvas.drawArc(150, 160, 100, 50, 180, 180);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is called `HappyFace` not `test`

```
<applet code="HappyFace" width = 700 height = 700> </applet>
```